# Is this the most normalised Database Entity Diagram I can use?

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

Recently I learnt about database normalisation and how it helps stop redundant data being added to a database etc. I was a little confused on how to normalise the database, is anyone able to tell me if this is normalised and a correct diagram?

[Database Entity Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/871yk.png)

Comment: Why do you want to separate `Login` from `User`? Is it for security purpose? Also if you have a many to many relationship like `User` to `Quiz`, you need to create a bridge table between the two like `UserQuiz` table for example to create two one-to-many relationship.

Comment: No. In addition to the above, any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2), you can be confident that your design is less than optimal.

Answer (score 0):

A more properly normalized structure might look something like this:

```
**user**
user_id
username
password
firstname
lastname

**quiz**
quiz_id
quizname

**questions**
question_id
quiz_id
points

**answer**
question_id
answer_no
answer
iscorrect
```